# Export class as interface in Angular2

Tags: angular, typescript, angular2-services

Is there a way to export a class as interface and then import that interface in another module in Angular 2? I need to be able to inject the class in a constructor in some components e.g should be registered as provider.

Comment: can you elaborate or provide a sample snippet to describe what you mean.. right now it is unclear..

Comment: @suraj which part is unclear?

Comment: do you mean in typescript?

Comment: @suraj yea, angular2 is only typescript i think

Comment: technically it can be in ts,js or dart..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In order to be used as both an interface and provider token, it may be abstract class. This is how it is done in Angular code base itself.

If concrete class has something to inherit from abstract class, the latter can be extendable:

```
export abstract class Foo {
  abstract bar();

  baz() { ... }
}

export class ConcreteFoo extends Foo {
  bar() { ... }
}

...
provider: [{ provide: Foo, useClass: ConcreteFoo }]
...
```

Otherwise it's safer to make abstract class non-extendable and non-instantiatable:

```
export abstract class Foo {
  private constructor() {
    throw new Error('should not be instantiated directly');
  }

  abstract bar();
}

export class ConcreteFoo implements Foo {
  bar() { ... }
}
```

It should be noticed that any class can be used as an interface in TypeScript. So if there's no real need to differentiate between interface and implementation, it may be just one concrete class:

```
export class Foo {
  bar() { ... }

  baz() { ... }
}

...
provider: [Foo]
...
```

Which may be used later as an interface if necessary:

```
export class SomeFoo implements Foo { ... }

...
provider: [{ provide: Foo, useClass: SomeFoo }]
...
```

Comment: It should be noted that this is not the same as an interface. For example, it introduces a value that can be instantiated at runtime. Not saying this is a bad solution, but use with caution. Also, implementing `Foo` as suggested in comments has a different meaning.

Comment: @AluanHaddad Question title differs from the real question, this was discussed in comments of a deleted answer. Since `Foo` is supposed to be a provider, yes, it will obviously exist in transpiled JS code. When abstract class is used only as an interface (e.g. `const foo: Foo = ...` and `... implements Foo ...`), it won't be transpiled - this is done frequently in Angular source code, too.

Comment: Indeed, I am simply saying that perhaps more description is warranted. Also, the Angular code base is riddled with code that should not be emulated. It has a nasty history, having been written in @Script, Dart, Dart2TS, TypeScript, and whatnot so it is not a good place to look for idiomatic TypeScript usage.

Comment: That's true. I guess in some cases they use abstract classes where they possibly intended to extend them later. Any way, having abstract class as an interface doesn't cause ill effects or extra output. I personally always add `constructor() { throw new Error('shouldn't be instantiated directly') }` to the abstracts that shouldn't be extended or instantiated accidentally.

Comment: That will cause failure if they are inherited though. Do you mean for classes that are meant to be listed in an `implements` clause only? If so you should use `private constructor() {throw Error('invalid');}` that way you get a compiler check as well

Comment: Yes, either that, or as in the case above - if `ConcreteFoo` has nothing to inherit from `Foo`, `Foo` may throw in its constructor, so a dev won't get noop service by chance with `provide: [Foo]`. Thanks for reminding about `private constructor`, that's a good one.

Comment: Good discussion. Cheers.

Comment: My pleasure. I decided to clarify the answer a bit, just in case if somebody will be confused by the title.