# Angular 4 DI through interfaces

Tags: angular, dependency-injection, code-injection

I followed documentation how to use InjectionToken for injection through interfaces. I just created a little project -

```
export interface MyInterface {
   sayHello();
}

@Injectable()
export class MyService implements MyInterface {
  sayHello()
  {
    throw new Error("Method not implemented.");
  }
}
```

My `app.module`

```
export let MY_SERVICE = new InjectionToken<MyInterface>('MY_SERVICE');
  providers: [
    {
      provide: MY_SERVICE,
      useClass : MyService
    }
],`
```

Here is `app.component.ts`

```
@Component({
selector: 'app-root',
templateUrl: './app.component.html',
styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
title = 'app';
constructor(@Inject(MY_SERVICE) private myService : MyInterface) {
  }
}
```

And that is an error I got in Chrome Tools

> compiler.es5.js:1690 Uncaught Error: Can't resolve all parameters for AppComponent: (?).
>       at syntaxError (compiler.es5.js:1690)
>       at CompileMetadataResolver.webpackJsonp.../../../compiler/@angular/compiler.es5.js.CompileMetadataResolver._getDependenciesMetadata (compiler.es5.js:15765)
>       at CompileMetadataResolver.webpackJsonp.../../../compiler/@angular/compiler.es5.js.CompileMetadataResolver._getTypeMetadata (

Here is plunkr - https://embed.plnkr.co/qQP5BhNzgu2F4FYclG1e/

Comment: I would expect it to work. The error will happen if MY_SERVICE wasn't registered in module providers. The code above is truncated and it's not known for sure that it was. Any way, it works better when abstract class is used as both an interface and a token.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Export class as interface in Angular2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43572149/export-class-as-interface-in-angular2)

Comment: @estus I do not think that it is duplicate, because I want use exact interface, not abstract class.  What do you mean by > MY_SERVICE wasn't registered in module providers ? I think I did it already

Comment: I considered it a duplicate because the thing you're trying to do is naturally achieved with abstract class, there's no real need for MY_SERVICE injection token. In the code above `MyInterface` shouldn't make a difference, you could do  `@Inject(MY_SERVICE) private myService : any` with same result. So unregistered MY_SERVICE is primary suspect. Consider providing http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve that can replicate the issue.

Comment: @estus Thanks. However I provided enough info. Please look at my question and find out - "My app.module" part. I provided the registration part for MY_SERVICE. As an update, will I get the type support if I do - `@Inject(MY_SERVICE) private myService : any` ? I do not think so

Comment: app.module isn't full. The code above will throw syntax error. Please, provide MCVE, it's required by the rules. A plunk or a fiddle will be fine. It's not possible to say what's wrong in your case because there's not enough information to make a conclusion.

Comment: @estus https://embed.plnkr.co/qQP5BhNzgu2F4FYclG1e/

Comment: Although abstract class is more natural way to do this (it doesn't require @Inject and is widely used in situations like that in Angular codebase itself), it would result in same problem. I posted the explanation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem in [original code](https://plnkr.co/edit/4o7m8KUHearLsZOhsiQB?p=preview) is that `MY_SERVICE` injection token is actually defined after it's used for injection.

To avoid this, it should be defined before that:

```
export let MY_SERVICE = new InjectionToken<MyInterface>('MY_SERVICE');
...
constructor(@Inject(MY_SERVICE) private myService: MyInterface) {
...
```

Alternatively, [`forwardRef`](https://angular.io/api/core/forwardRef) helper could be used, it's designed to avoid race conditions like that:

```
...
constructor(@Inject(forwardRef(() => MY_SERVICE)) private myService: MyInterface) {
...
export let MY_SERVICE = new InjectionToken<MyInterface>('MY_SERVICE');
```

This usually won't be a problem for a real application where providers and places where they are used are located in different module files.