# Typescript: type method params implementing base class

Tags: typescript, class, implements

I'm working with TypeScript, and I want to create an interface or type for a `MyClass` class. I want to be able to type the input parameters of the methods of `MyClass`, so I implement a BaseClass, which uses some types for input and output values.
The issue is that, when hovering the parameters of the methods of `myClass`, —`myString` at `MyClass` `methodOne`, for example—, the type is `any`, while it should be `string`.

```
type ComplexObject1 = {
  myString: string;
};

type ComplexObject2 = {
  myNumber: number;
};

interface BaseClass {
  methodOne: (params: ComplexObject1) => number;
  methodTwo: (params: ComplexObject2) => string;
}

class MyClass implements BaseClass {
  methodOne({ myString }) {
    return myString.length;
  }
  methodTwo({ myNumber }) {
    return String(myNumber);
  }
}
```

I tried also setting `BaseClass` as interface or abstract class, or with the methods with different syntax, with same results:

```
type BaseClass = {
  methodOne: (params: ComplexObject1) => number;
  methodTwo: (params: ComplexObject2) => string;
};
```

or

```
abstract class BaseClass {
  methodOne: (params: ComplexObject1) => number;
  methodTwo: (params: ComplexObject2) => string;
}
```

or

```
interface BaseClass {
  methodOne(params: ComplexObject1): number;
  methodTwo(params: ComplexObject2): string;
}
```

What I am doing wrong here?

EDIT: this question was proposed as an answer: [Typescript: Use class as interface](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47114181/typescript-use-class-as-interface)
It is an interesting read, but it doesn't answer the question of how to type the input params of each method.

EDIT2: This is the only solution I can think of, but is not satisfactory; I was expecting using an abstract class or an interface to implement/extend instead of separate function types:

```
type ComplexObject1 = {
  myString: string;
};

type ComplexObject2 = {
  myNumber: number;
};

type MyClassMethodOne = (params: ComplexObject1) => number;
type MyClassMethodTwo = (params: ComplexObject2) => string;

class MyClass {
  methodOne: MyClassMethodOne = ({ myString }) => {
    return myString.length;
  };
  methodTwo: MyClassMethodTwo = ({ myNumber }) => {
    return String(myNumber);
  };
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Typescript: Use class as interface](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47114181/typescript-use-class-as-interface)

Comment: Lots of thanks @ArtemeeSenin. Really interesting, but it doesn't focus on how to type the input params of the methods of the class from an abstract class/interface/type

Comment: That's a good question, all the examples I ve seen they redeclare the types.