# Creating plain object with class type definition

Tags: javascript, typescript

Assume we have the following class:

```
class A {
  private maxValue = 900;
  public minValue = 800;
  someMethod() {}
}
```

And I want to create a plain object with the class type definition:

```
const objA: A = {
  minValue: 200,
  maxValue: 2313,
  someMethod() {}
};
```

And I'm getting this error:

> Property 'maxValue' is private in type 'A' but not in type '{
> minValue: number; maxValue: number; someMethod(): void; }

The question is: Does it make sense to create objects in this way? or Should I always stick with `new A()`

Comment: But why? Aren't you looking for [interface](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html) or [object inheritance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47114181/typescript-use-class-as-interface)?

Comment: I think this can be the case when mocking classes for unit testing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it does not make too much sense. If you check `objA instanceof A` it will return `false`, although your code states it would be an instance of class A. And as you can see a plain object can not have private properties whereas a class instance can. So better stick to `new A()` or use interfaces.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it's an ideal way to define an object with this type. If you want to define an object like this, use an interface instead of a class. In case of creating new object regarding class A, `new A()` is a better solution for creating a new object.