# Can I have a class automatically "inherit" properties from an Interface to avoid explicitly defining them?

Tags: typescript

I would like to be able define a TypeScript interface like so:

```
interface SquareConfig {
   color: string;
   width: number;
}
```

and then have a class that implements said interface, and to automatically have properties that match the interface without manually defining them. Like so:

```
class MyClass implements SquareConfig {
    // magic code that eliminates need to duplicate property definitions from Interface
}

let mc = new MyClass()
mc.color = 'blue' // works
mc.width = 12 // works
```

I want to avoid:

```
class MyClass implements SquareConfig {
    color: string;
    width: number;
}
```

My rationale is that I have a non-trivial number of properties, and it's useful for me to do type checking at runtime for JSON objects using a library like `typia`, hence the interface. I then want to be able to take that type-checked JSON and initialize a class instance, where the class implements the same interface. I'd rather not manually have to define all those properties in the class, because:

1. It's unnecessarily verbose, and violates "DRY"
2. I have to keep the properties from the class and interface in sync

I'm guessing there is no way to do what I want, but if there is, great, or if there is another approach that fits my use case happy to hear that.

Comment: The closest case I can think of is when inheriting from a class that has already provided member implementations. In that case re-implementing them is not needed.

Comment: You could use declaration merging as shown [here](https://tsplay.dev/N9jAMm); does that approach meet your needs? If so I could write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to the comment from @Joe McCarty I did some digging, and found a way to make this work. Implement the properties in a base class, create an interface that extends the class, then in your "real" class extend the base class and implement the interface.

```
class SquareConfig{
    color: string;
    width: number;
}

interface SquareConfigInterface extends SquareConfig{}

class MyClass 
  extends SquareConfig
  implements SquareConfigInterface {
}

let mc = new MyClass()

mc.color = 'blue'
mc.width = 2

console.log(mc)
```

You'll see that if you remove the `extends SquareConfig`, the TypeScript compiler will start complaining that `MyClass` is missing `color` and `width`.

Credit also to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47116527/187812)

Comment: I don't see the `SquareConfigInterface` doing any work here; why not just write `class SquareConfig {color: string = "plsinitialize"; width: number = 0;}` and then `class MyClass extends SquareConfig {}`?  Is there something `SquareConfigInterface` is supposed to do?

Comment: In my original post, I call out my motivation as having an interface to use for a dynamic type checking library typia.  Now that I know about the class extends trick, maybe I could even use the base class with typia and avoid the interface altogether. I will have to test it.

Comment: Sure enough typia accepts the base class for validation, so technically I don't need the interface.